# particular solution of $4y''+16y'+17y=e^{-2t}\sin\frac{t}{2}+6t\cos\frac{t}{2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$4y''+16y'+17y=e^{-2t}\sin(\frac{t}{2})+6t\cos(\frac{t}{2})$$

Shouldn't it the guess be:

$$y_{p}=e^{-2t}\left(A\sin(\frac{t}{2})+B\cos(\frac{t}{2})\right)+(Ct+D)\left(\cos(\frac{t}{2})+\sin(\frac{t}{2})\right)$$?

Comment: As long as the coefficients are solvable, the guess should be correct.

Comment: See https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4y%27%27%2B16y%27%2B17y%3De%5E%7B-2t%7D%5Csin(%5Cfrac%7Bt%7D%7B2%7D)%2B6t%5Ccos(%5Cfrac%7Bt%7D%7B2%7D).

Comment: @hkmather802 http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/UndeterminedCoefficients.aspx#Second_UnderCoeff_Ex10c gave a different answer

Comment: @gbox you can use Laplace transform to solve this!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the solutions of the characteristic equation are $-2\pm{i\over2}$. It follows that $e^{-2t}\sin{t\over2}$ is a solution of the corresponding homogeneous equation. You should take care of this in your "Ansatz" for $y_p$.